# Is it true that $\frac1n<\sum\limits_{j=n}^{m}\frac{1}{j^2}<\frac1n+\frac1{m^2}$ for $n\geq2$ and $m=\lceil 2n^2-\frac{2}{3}n \rceil$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> Let $n\geq 2$ and $m=\lceil 2n^2-\frac{2}{3}n \rceil$. Is it true
>   that
>   $$
> \sum_{j=n}^{m}\frac{1}{j^2} > \frac{1}{n} > \sum_{j=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{j^2}\ ?
> $$

I have checked this for $n\leq 40$.

My thoughts : The classical comparison with an integral
yields $$\sum\limits_{j=n}^{m}\frac{1}{j^2} 
\geq \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{m+1}$$ which is close but not enough.

Comment: Interesting question, +1. What is the context where it arose?

Comment: Verified for $n<380$ using Sage. Trying to get the computation to $500$, but it takes increasingly long time for each $n$.

Comment: @Did Here is the context : it is easy to show "ineffectively" that $\sum_{j=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2} \geq \frac{1}{n}$ (because by a sum-integral comparison, the sequence $u_n=n(\sum_{j=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}) (n\geq 2)$ is decreasing and converges to $1$). Trying to get a more effective bound led me to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we get that
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\
&=\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{6n^3}-\frac1{30n^5}+\frac1{42n^7}-\frac1{30n^9}+O\left(\frac1{n^{11}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{\left\lceil2n^2-\frac23n\right\rceil}\frac1{k^2}
&=f(n)-f\!\left(\left\lceil2n^2-\tfrac23n\right\rceil+1\right)\\
&\ge f(n)-f\!\left(2n^2-\tfrac23n+1\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac1n+\frac5{72n^4}+\frac{17}{540n^5}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{\left\lceil2n^2-\frac23n\right\rceil-1}\frac1{k^2}
&=f(n)-f\left(\left\lceil2n^2-\tfrac23n\right\rceil\right)\\
&\le f(n)-f\left(2n^2-\tfrac23n+\tfrac23\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac1n-\frac1{72n^4}-\frac{13}{540n^5}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What does $f\!\left(2n^2-\tfrac23n+1\right)$ mean when $2n^2-\tfrac23n+1$ is not an integer ? I think I see : $f:{\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb R}$ has a continous, monotonous extension $g:{\mathbb R}^{+} \to {\mathbb R}$ for which the asymptotic expansion still holds.

Comment: The Euler-Maclaurin Formula gives an asymptotic approximation for a sum. $f(x)$ is a decreasing function approximated by the series, which equals the sum when $x\in\mathbb{N}$. This is why I under/over-estimated the ceiling function by functions to which the series is more easily applied. These approximations are only good for "large enough" $n$. However, the first $4$ terms of the expansion have an error that is smaller than $\frac1{42n^7}$ for $n\ge1$.

Comment: However, as you've checked the inequality for $n\le40$, the approximations above should be very good for $n\gt40$.